# Bundled Notifications on older Android Versions

Tags: android, notifications, android-7.1-nougat

Is it possible to make bundled **notifications(introduced in Android Nougat)** on older Android Versions? The question is only about handheld devices and tablets and NOT **android wear**.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. The closest that you can come is to use an expanded notification style (e.g., `BigMessageStyle`) with a single notification that embeds information that you would prefer to use with bundled notifications on Android 7.0+.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I lost one day searching about this. I've tried using **setGroup()** and **setGroupSummary()** methods but on handheld devices it only shows the summary notification. Thanks again :)